# how do you make resizeable work in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I have bunch of divs that I would like to set it to resizable but I don't seem to get it work:

I have included the following on my page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#popup_box" ).draggable();
    $( "#app1_cpu" ).draggable();
    $( "#app1_cpu" ).resizable();
});
</script>
```

draggable is working but not resizeable () any ideas what I might missing here?

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gsaray101/RveaK/3/

looks like the chart is covering the resizable image. Any ideas how could move the resizable image outside of the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coding working fine.  Maybe some `JS` file conflict.

Better try using links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H6Mpt/1/).

Comment: I know what the problem is but dont know how to fix it. I have bunch of divs that I am put highcharts in them, when the document is loading, I can see the resiable images but when the document loads, those images disappear. How could I bring those image to the front, that is the question?

Comment: @user1471980 Is possible to share a fiddle?

Comment: @user1471980 JSfiddle it self provide scripts attachments.  so no need.  You had more error of missing } and ).  now check this http://jsfiddle.net/RveaK/4/ and share the missing parts.

Comment: it works if the chart is not in the div. When I put the chart in the div, I dont see the resizable image, I've updated your jsfiddle, can you take a look?

Comment: I think you missed to add the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

If you want the id #app1_cpu to be both draggable and resizeable, try doing this:

```
 $("#app1_cpu").draggable().resizable();
```

Comment: I tried that dragabble works but not the resizable. Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: [Take a look at my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JdN2u). Make sure you have the latest jQuery and jQueryUI.